# docker-compose with podman secret - mounting error

Tags: docker-compose, podman

First in shell script, I create the secret with `podman` secret create
then I try to use it inside the `docker-compose.yml`. Then in `shell script` when I try to run `docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```
Error response from daemon: runc: runc create failed: unable to start container process: 
error during container init: error mounting "/var/lib/some-dir/tmp/secret_name.sec" 
to rootfs at "/run/secrets/secret_name": 
open /var/lib/containers/storage/overlay/b3eaa7599a7376c1c989bd7861859db208cbfb962d274bb640accfe62e7185a0/merged/run/secrets/secret_name: 
read-only file system: OCI runtime error
```

I am using :

- CentOS 8
- Docker Compose v2.19.0
- yml version: 3.8
- podman version:
- Client: Podman Engine Version: 4.3.1
- API Version: 4.3.1
- Go Version: go1.19.4
- Built: Tue Jan 31 22:06:15 2023
- OS/Arch: linux/amd64

What I am doing wrong?